# RMAN restore up to current

Tags: oracle, rman

Oracle 11.2.0.3 restoring to 11.2.0.4

Without going full blown Data Guard, how can I get Oracle to restore to a fairly current (within the last hour or two) state?  Moving the datafiles over takes about 12 hours, so I can't do a full blown restore in the timeframe.

So I was thinking I could move them over and keep moving the archivelogs over up into the point I want to restore and then replay all the logs since the datafiles move...BUT the logs only seem to want to replay until the point that I started the restore 12 hours earlier.  What else besides copying needs to happen?

Comment: So what is your actual question? Yes, it is possible. Simply just copying the archivelogs is not enough. The other database will not find them unless you show it where to search: `RMAN> catalog start with '/path/to/logs/';`. Maybe that is the only step you missed and it would explain why recovery can not go any further.

Comment: Ah!  That's probably it!

Comment: You said "Oracle 11.2.0.3 restoring to 11.2.0.4"  So what are your plans to deal with the version difference, and why are you restoring a backup of an 11.2.0.3 to 11.2.0.4 ?

Comment: Why is a complicated reason involving moving to new hardware and bug fixes.  Dealing with the version difference is just "startup upgrade" and a particular oracle supplied script to transform the catalog.